# Como mostrar un botón con jquery dentro de ajax en asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Hola comunidad estoy tratando de ocultar mi botón y mostrarlo dentro del success de ajax al dar clic a otro botón. Pero solo aparece por un momento y vuelve a desaparecer. A

```js
 function obtener_Persona() {
 
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "frmPersona.aspx/Personas",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{id_Persona:"' + id_Persona + '",Puesto:"' + Puesto + '",id_Rol:"' + id_Rol + '"}',
        async: false,

        success: function(data) {
            
            if (data != '') {
            //Este es el boton que quiero que se muestre dentro del ajax
            $("#btnEnviar").prop('visibility', 'visible');  
            
           }
        }
   });
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
 <div class="row">           
            <div class="col">   
            <%-- Este es el primer boton al darle clic quiero que el boton de abajo se muestre --%>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnBuscar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                     OnClientClick="return obtener_Persona();"><span class="fas fa-search"></span></asp:LinkButton>               
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
   
  <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col offset-10">                   
                        <button id="btnEnviar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PopupConfirmarBI" style="visibility:hidden">Enviar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>           
    </div>
```

.

Comment: Intenta agregar `return false;` al final de la funcion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es qu estas usando un `boton link de asp.net` lo cual genera un evento al servidor, actualizando la pagina que la recarga poniendo los estados como al principio

Cambia tu boton `asp:LinkButton` a uno de html `<button>` asi no tendras el evento al servidor

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">           
        <div class="col">   
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="return obtener_Persona();">
                <span class="fas fa-search"></span>
            </button>               
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

no mezcles controles asp.net con acciones que realizas con codigo cliente es para problemas